# UITableviewCell Deselected callback

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a custom  UItableviewcell  (I have subclassed it ) . I have to change it's selection style on select and revert the changes when some other cell has been selected . I have a callback setSelectionStyle where I can change the look and feel to show that its selected but I dont have a callback to revert that change .

Any Idea how does apple removes that blue layer of selection from UItableviewcell ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


   /*

     All required implementation with the selected row 

   */

    // Use the following code to deselect the row.
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Note : Do not forget to add the tableview delegate in your .m file.

Comment: Oh ,  so its a callback in tableview . I was looking in UItableview cell. Thanks !! It worked